# MySQL trigger to fire on alter or drop

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've encountered an interesting problem. I would like to create two triggers, trigger1 would fire on `DROP TABLE` and trigger2 on `ALTER TABLE`. I would like trigger1 and trigger2 to fire if any table is dropped or altered, but, unfortunately I don't know the syntax to do that and I couldn't find a syntax for such triggers either. In MySQL I can only write triggers which fire before/after `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`, but now I would like to write triggers which would be applicable on database level and would fire on table events. Can somebody help me?

Comment: @Mythje: that for sql-server. He asked about MySql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as "DDL Triggers". MySQL does not support them

There is this [SourceForge request](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=2418) but I'm not sure how serious anyone is about adding it

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! However, I hope you are not right and they have a solution for this. I'll wait for other answers too and will continue the researching and if I find a solution I'll answer my question myself. If not, I'll probably accept yours. Thank you.

Comment: Your link points to nothing today, but I found [this Worklog entry](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418); hope it helps :-)

Comment: @watery above link is for oracle or sql server not for mysql syntax are not working in mysql

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a trigger for drop statements.According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) the trigger is activated on

- **INSERT**: The trigger is activated whenever a new row is inserted into the table; for example, through INSERT, LOAD DATA, and REPLACE
  statements.

  **UPDATE**: The trigger is activated whenever a row is modified; for example, through UPDATE statements.

  **DELETE**: The trigger is activated whenever a row is deleted from the table; for example, through DELETE and REPLACE statements.
  *However, DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE TABLE statements on the table do not activate this trigger, because they do not use DELETE*.

It doesn't say anything about alter table, but I would expect only DML-statements to be able to fire a trigger.

Comment: +1 I've read the documentation and didn't find what I was looking for, but your answer might be useful for other SO users who didn't read the documentation.

Comment: The TRUNCATE TABLE statement when using InnoDB will always use DELETE on MySQL prior to 5.0.3 and after will use DELETE when there are constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE `pr_new_type`( IN column_name varchar(10) )
BEGIN
SET @queryText = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `user_rights` ADD ', column_name, ' BINARY( 9 ) NULL');
PREPARE query FROM @queryText;
EXECUTE query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
END
```

test this

Comment: This is a procedure, not a trigger. Also, my question referred to two triggers, which will run on alter and drop commands, respectively.